# Error using substr()

Tags: php

I am getting error while using `substr`:

> Warning: substr() expects parameter 3 to be long

I am new to php and could not locate the problem. I would appreciate any help.

Here is the code:

```
function prepare_string($passed_string,$length)
    {
        $matches = array("`","!","@","®","©","~","#","$","%","^","&","*","-","=","+","|","\\","[","{","]","}","(",")",";",":","\"","'",",","<",">",".","?","/","\'","\\","'","’");
        $passed_string =substr($passed_string,0,$length);
        for($i=0;$i<count($matches);$i++)
        {
            $passed_string = str_replace($matches[$i],"_",$passed_string);
        }
        $passed_string = str_replace(" ","_",$passed_string);
        return $passed_string;
    }
```

Comment: What defines `$length`?

Comment: `var_dump($length)` will tell you what you're trying to stuff into substr()

Comment: $length value might not coming the right value.

Comment: FYI: `str_replace` takes an array too, so you can throw away your for loop.

Comment: $length needs to be an integer value 0 or more. As others suggested, dump out $length and see if it's defined (set), and what kind of value it has.

Answer (score 0):

1. `var_dump($length)` and see what's in there.
2. remove foreach loop and instead put just this line `$passed_string = str_replace($matches,"_",$passed_string);`
3. add `" "` in $matches array too and then you can get rid of this line `$passed_string = str_replace(" ","_",$passed_string);`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `substr()` is not receiving a well-formed value for some reason... One option would be to add a line inside the function that casts `$length` as an integer. Example:

```
function prepare_string($passed_string,$length)
    {
        // Add this line
        $length = (int) $length;
        $matches = array("`","!","@","®","©","~","#","$","%","^","&","*","-","=","+","|","\\","[","{","]","}","(",")",";",":","\"","'",",","<",">",".","?","/","\'","\\","'","’");
        $passed_string =substr($passed_string,0,$length);
        for($i=0;$i<count($matches);$i++)
        {
            $passed_string = str_replace($matches[$i],"_",$passed_string);
        }
        $passed_string = str_replace(" ","_",$passed_string);
        return $passed_string;
    }
```